# Create an xml with input parameters to a stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I was learning how to write stored procedures in SQL Server. I wanted to write a procedure where I can pass an xml parameter with the input parameters and the stored procedure would return me a "success" or a "failure" response in case the insertion is successful in the db.

I am a bit stuck as how should I go about it. This is what I tried so far.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE Procedure [dbo].[p_addfeeddata]
    (@thearticle VARCHAR(200),
     @thearticlelink VARCHAR(200),
     @thepublicationdate VARCHAR(200),
     @theviewednumberoftimes VARCHAR(200),
     @articlexml xml)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO RSSFeeddetails (Title, Link, PublicationDate, ViewedNumber) 
    VALUES (@thearticle, @thearticlelink, @thepublicationdate, @theviewednumberoftimes);
END
```

My idea is that I will pass create an xml and then I will pass the xml to my stored procedure for inserting the data in the table

Comment: Best practice is for failure to be indicated by errors.  SQL Server will generate these and send them to the client or you can create them yourself with THROW https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql.

Comment: The xml parameter is declared but not used in the proc. You'll of course need to add that to the insert statement if your intent is to insert the XML value into the `RSSFeeddetails` table. I suggest you follow David's advice, which requires no additional code to return errors.

Comment: There are a few open questions: What is the structure of the XML document, where do you want to add it, how should the XML document be stored?

Comment: Do I understand this correctly: You want to replace all your parameters with one single XML parameter, do some action and return a status?